# Reporting cpu hogs

Tags: power-management, process-management

Once in a while some program (ok, usually it's firefox) will start eating up nearly 100% of a processor's cpu time, heating up the processor and driving down by laptop's battery life. Since it's not bad enough to impact performance, I usually don't notice for a while, so I'd like to change this:

Is there a utility that **monitors process cpu usage and popus up an alert** if some process is using a lot of cpu time for an extended period of time (e.g., more than 30 seconds)? I can probably rig something up with ps or top, sed and a bunch of pipes, but I'm hoping there's a more direct way to do it.

**Edit:** On second thought, what I'm really after is power usage. So any instrumentation specifically targeted at estimating power consumption is of particular interest.

I'm on OS X 10.8, but welcome Linux-specific solutions as well.

Comment: There is `cpulimit` on `Debian` based OSes. Check out [CPU Usage Limiter for Linux](http://cpulimit.sourceforge.net/) & [cpulimit on github](https://github.com/opsengine/cpulimit)

Comment: Interesting, thanks. It would be useful in cases where a single process must be slowed down, but less so for monitoring the system.

Comment: oh, I thought you wanted to pin the cause; I remember using `Monit` utility on production servers. [Monit Utility](http://mmonit.com/monit/)

Answer (score 2):

#### Rolling your own with Zenity

I'm not aware of any out of the box tool that will do this for you. I'd write a script to watch for the situation and then use something like [`zenity`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zenity) to pop a dialog up when the situation arises.

```
$ zenity --info --text="This is an information box."
```

[image: ss of zenity dialog]

It's pretty easy to get started with it and it's extremely easy to embed these dialogs into crons and scripts if need be.

#### Conky

I personally use [`conky`](http://conky.sourceforge.net/) to keep an eye on things that are going on, on my system. It's highly configurable and can be coupled to your background so that it's always easily accessible.

[image: conky]

#### Putting them together?

As a novel solution to your problem you could setup `conky` to watch for a particular situation, such as a process consuming all of your CPU resources, and then popping a dialog alerting you to the problem. I found this solution which shows a warning dialog being displayed when the battery got below a certain threshold. This solution was in a post titled: [Low Battery Warning Using conky](http://ifacethoughts.net/2010/09/24/low-battery-warning-using-conky/).

```
   BATTERY: ${color}${battery BAT0}
    ${if_match ${battery_percent BAT0} <= 10}
    ${if_match "${acpiacadapter}" == "off-line"}
    ${exec zenity --warning --text "Low Battery"}
    ${endif}
    ${endif}
```

Comment: Thanks for both tips. Does Conky warn you when something starts hogging the cpu?